# Symfony2 form collection not calling addxxx and removexxx even if 'by_reference' => false

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections, doctrine

I have the Customer entity and two one-to-many relations CustomerPhone and CustomerAddress.

The Customer entity has addPhone/removePhone and addAddress/removeAddress "adders".

CustomerType collections options has 'by_reference' => false for both collections.

Entity functions addPhone/removePhone and addAddress/removeAddress not called after form submitted, so CustomerPhone and CustomerAddress have no parent id after persist.

Why could addPhone/removePhone and addAddress/removeAddress not called on form submit?

**UPD 1.**

After @Baig [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358989/symfony2-form-collection-not-calling-addxxx-and-removexxx-even-if-by-reference#comment54516731_33358989) now I have addPhone/removePhone "adders" called, but addAddress/removeAddress not. Can't get why because they are identical.

```
 # TestCustomerBundle/Entity/Customer.php

 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CustomerPhone", mappedBy="customerId", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $phone;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CustomerAddress", mappedBy="customerId", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $address;
```

Same file "adders"

```
# TestCustomerBundle/Entity/Customer.php
/**
 * Add customer phone.
 *
 * @param Phone $phone
 */
public function addPhone(CustomerPhone $phone) {
    $phone->setCustomerId($this);
    $this->phone->add($phone);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove customer phone.
 *
 * @param Phone $phone customer phone
 */
public function removePhone(CustomerPhone $phone) {
    $this->phone->remove($phone);
}
/**
 * Add customer address.
 *
 * @param Address $address
 */
public function addAddress(CustomerAddress $address) {
    $address->setCustomerId($this);
    $this->address->add($address);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove customer address.
 *
 * @param Address $address customer address
 */
public function removeAddress(CustomerAddress $address) {
    $this->address->remove($address);
}
```

Relations:

```
# TestCustomerBundle/Entity/CustomerPhone.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="phone")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $customerId;

#TestCustomerBundle/Entity/CustomerAddress.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="address")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $customerId;
```

CustomerType form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('phone', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new CustomerPhoneType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'options' => array('label' => false)
        ))
        ->add('address', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new CustomerAddressType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'options' => array('label' => false)
        ))
        ->add('submit', 'submit')
    ;
}
```

Controller.

```
# TestCustomerBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $customer = new Customer();
        // Create form.
        $form = $this->createForm(new CustomerType(), $customer);
        // Handle form to store customer obect with doctrine.
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
        {
            $form->bind($request);
            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                /*$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($customer);
                $em->flush();*/
                $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'New customer added');
            }
        }
        // Display form.
        return $this->render('DeliveryCrmBundle:Default:customer_form.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

**UPD 2.**
Test if addAddress called.

```
/**
     * Add customer address.
     *
     * @param Address $address
     */
    public function addAddress(Address $address) {
        jkkh; // Test for error if method called. Nothing throws.
        $address->setCustomerId($this);
        $this->address->add($address);        
    }
```

**UPD 3.**

CustomerAddressType.php

```
<?php

namespace Delivery\CrmBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CustomerAddressType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('street')
            ->add('house')
            ->add('building', 'text', ['required' => false])
            ->add('flat', 'text', ['required' => false])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Delivery\CrmBundle\Entity\CustomerAddress'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'delivery_crmbundle_customeraddress';
    }
}
```

CustomerPhoneType.php

```
<?php

namespace Delivery\CrmBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CustomerPhoneType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('number')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Delivery\CrmBundle\Entity\CustomerPhone'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'phone';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're seeing?  It's hard to tell what you think the problem is.

Comment: @kdbanman entity functions addPhone/removePhone and addAddress/removeAddress are not called after form is submitted. It's not working like it's described here symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html So, CustomerPhone and CustomerAddress have no parent id after persist. 

The question updated.

Comment: can you try removing `$em->persist($customer);` and then try it. I am also using collection type everything seems to be setup right, i am using `yml` though but that should not make a difference. For now just try removing `$em->flush();` I also don't understand the purpose of everything above your form creation , i dont think you need that

Comment: When you are using a `collectionType` symfony automatically looks for the `add` method so you do not have to specify that in controller so i will recommend you to remove the code above `$form = $this->createForm(new CustomerType(), $customer);`

Comment: @Baig Thank you. This is patrially helped. Now I have addPhone/removePhone called, but not addAddress/removeAddress. CustomerAddress still saving without customer id. Controller code in question updated.

Comment: did you try removing `$em->persist($customer);` I still see it on your action

Comment: @Baig yes. I can't understand why, but setAddress instead addAddress is called. For addPhone all sems working.

Comment: @Baig I've just comment out all $em section and it works, but Address saved with customer_id set to NULL, because addAddress not called at all. I guess it can be because of guessing plural form of these methods, but not shure. 

Update code with addAddress example.

Comment: Sorry that you are still stuck with this, can you also add code of `CustomerPhoneType` and `CustomerAddressType` also so i can check

Comment: @Baig done. `CustomerPhoneType` and `CustomerAddressType` added. I see diffrence between `public function getName()` in that types, I'll check if problem is there.

Comment: @Baig I've change `delivery_crmbundle_customeraddress` to `address` but no luck.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine as far as I can see, i will recommend you to get some by posting your question here http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony2-ep2 I am sure you will get some there

Answer (score 10):

For me this was eventually solved by adding `getXXX`, which returns the collection to the `PropertyAccessor`. Without that you keep on wondering why `addXXX` or `removeXXX` aren't called.

So make sure that:

- The option `by_reference` is set to `false` at the field,
- You have both the `adder` and `remover` method on the owning side of the relationship,
- The `getter` is accessible for the `PropertyAccessor` to check if `by_reference` can be used,
- If you want to use the `prototype` to handle adding/removing via Javascript, make sure `allow_add` is set to `true`.

Answer (score 5):

This answer corresponds to Symfony 3, but I am sure this applies to Symfony 2 as well. Also this answer is more as a reference than addressing OP's issue in particular (which I am not to clear)

On `..Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php` the method `writeProperty` is responsible for calling either `setXXXXs` or `addXXX` & `removeXXXX` methods.

So here is order on which it looks for the method:

1. If the entity is `array` or instance of `Traversable` (which `ArrayCollection` is) then pair of

   - `addEntityNameSingular()`
   - `removeEntityNameSingular()`

     Source for reference:

     ```
     if (is_array($value) || $value instanceof \Traversable) {
         $methods = $this->findAdderAndRemover($reflClass, $singulars);

         if (null !== $methods) {
             $access[self::ACCESS_TYPE] = self::ACCESS_TYPE_ADDER_AND_REMOVER;
             $access[self::ACCESS_ADDER] = $methods[0];
             $access[self::ACCESS_REMOVER] = $methods[1];
         }
     }
     ```
2. If not then:

   1. `setEntityName()`
   2. `entityName()`
   3. `__set()`
   4. `$entity_name` (Should be public)
   5. `__call()`

      Source for reference:

      ```
      if (!isset($access[self::ACCESS_TYPE])) {
          $setter = 'set'.$camelized;
          $getsetter = lcfirst($camelized); // jQuery style, e.g. read: last(), write: last($item)

          if ($this->isMethodAccessible($reflClass, $setter, 1)) {
              $access[self::ACCESS_TYPE] = self::ACCESS_TYPE_METHOD;
              $access[self::ACCESS_NAME] = $setter;
          } elseif ($this->isMethodAccessible($reflClass, $getsetter, 1)) {
              $access[self::ACCESS_TYPE] = self::ACCESS_TYPE_METHOD;
              $access[self::ACCESS_NAME] = $getsetter;
          } elseif ($this->isMethodAccessible($reflClass, '__set', 2)) {
              $access[self::ACCESS_TYPE] = self::ACCESS_TYPE_PROPERTY;
              $access[self::ACCESS_NAME] = $property;
          } elseif ($access[self::ACCESS_HAS_PROPERTY] && $reflClass->getProperty($property)->isPublic()) {
              $access[self::ACCESS_TYPE] = self::ACCESS_TYPE_PROPERTY;
              $access[self::ACCESS_NAME] = $property;
          } elseif ($this->magicCall && $this->isMethodAccessible($reflClass, '__call', 2)) {
              // we call the getter and hope the __call do the job
              $access[self::ACCESS_TYPE] = self::ACCESS_TYPE_MAGIC;
              $access[self::ACCESS_NAME] = $setter;
          } else {
              $access[self::ACCESS_TYPE] = self::ACCESS_TYPE_NOT_FOUND;
              $access[self::ACCESS_NAME] = sprintf(
                  'Neither the property "%s" nor one of the methods %s"%s()", "%s()", '.
                  '"__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "%s".',
                  $property,
                  implode('', array_map(function ($singular) {
                      return '"add'.$singular.'()"/"remove'.$singular.'()", ';
                  }, $singulars)),
                  $setter,
                  $getsetter,
                  $reflClass->name
              );
          }
      }
      ```

To answer OP's issue, based on the above mentioned information, the PropertyAccessor class of symfony is not able to read your `addXX` and `removeXX` method properly. The potential reason might be that is not identified as `array` or `ArrayCollection` which has to be done from the constructor of the entity

```
public function __construct() {
     $this->address = new ArrayCollection();
     // ....
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter, I would like to know what is wrong with the answer please.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I'm not sure that it's the same cause.

I your entity's attribute that has OneToMany relation ship must have an 's' at the end. So that in "handleRequest" (leave it a black box, I didn't look up inside), symfony would find your "addxxx" without "s".

In the exemple '[Task - Tag](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)', he declared "tags" but getTag.

In your case I would think you change your $phone to $phones and the method follow:

```
public function setPhones($phones){}
public function addPhone(Phone $phone){}
```

To the name of method your form searching for, just delete temporarily setter in your entity and submit your form, symfony will told you.

Just hope this would help you out :)